# How do I update data embedded in the HTML script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html page with Json-ld data embedded in the script tag.

How do I update this data on the submit of a form?

Here is some of the code of the page (data + load function). What I'm missing is the saveData function that updates the data embedded in the script section.

Thank you,

```
    <script id="person" type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "givenName": "Marco",
  "familyName": "Van Basten"
}
</script>
<script>
function loadData() {

  var person = document.getElementById("person").textContent;
  var jsonld = JSON.parse(person);


  document.getElementById("givenName").value = jsonld.givenName;
  document.getElementById("familyName").value = jsonld.familyName;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything that didn't work?

Comment: You obviously need to do this on the server side, if you are actually submitting the form.

Comment: I used an action on the form with a javascript function linked: "form action="javascript:saveData()". Inside this I can update the entire script but not the single data parts ...

Comment: It's not necessarily obvious. I don't know why this is done in JSON instead of just plain JS, but there's no reason the `innerText` of `person` couldn't be updated based on an XHR response.

Comment: Oh, and there's the problem. Instead of doing a form submit, you need to add a click handler to something (link, button, whatever) that creates and sends an XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Maybe I can try to retrieve the entire JSON, parse it, update it and then rewrite it entirely to the script part... I will try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet is **for example only**, but should show you how to update your script object with the JSON string using `JSON.stringify`.

```
  person.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonld);
```

Load the original by using Load. Change the values then Save and Load again.
Use the browser developer tools to watch the values of the DOM.

```js
function loadData(e) {

  var person = document.getElementById("person");
  var jsonld = JSON.parse(person.textContent);
  console.log(jsonld.givenName, jsonld);

  document.getElementById("givenName").value = jsonld.givenName;
  document.getElementById("familyName").value = jsonld.familyName;

}

function saveData(e) {
  console.log('event', e);
  var person = document.getElementById("person");
  var jsonld = JSON.parse(person.textContent);
  
  jsonld.givenName =document.getElementById("givenName").value;
  jsonld.familyName =document.getElementById("familyName").value;
  
  //person.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonld);
  person.textContent = JSON.stringify(jsonld);
}

document.getElementById("saveButton").addEventListener('click', saveData);
document.getElementById("loadButton").addEventListener('click',loadData);
```

```html
<script id="person" type="application/ld+json">
  { "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "Person", "givenName": "Marco", "familyName": "Van Basten" }
</script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="givenName" />
  <input type="text" id="familyName" />
</form>
<button id="loadButton">Load</button>
<button id="saveButton">Save</button>
```

Comment: **Notice:** I changed the person object to be the element itself for reference purposes and completeness.

Comment: Perfect, it is what I wanted!